# adjust UWP ContentDialog width/height

Tags: uwp

Is it possible to adjust UWP ContentDialog width/height?
I tried to adjust ContentDialog.Width, but nothing changed

[image]

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to adjust UWP ContentDialog width/height?

`ContentDialog` will adjust size base on it's content, if you give the content specific height and width, `ContentDialog` size will be changed.

```
<ContentDialog>
    <Grid Height="600" Width="400">
        
    </Grid>
</ContentDialog>
```